Why is it working only when I use upper case "CONDA" in git bash?
image
I'm using VSCode for editor.
When I enter conda in lower case letter in git bash, it says
bash: D:naconda3\Scripts: No such file or directory
But when I checked my bash_profiles it says
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
if [ -f '/d/anaconda3/Scripts/conda.exe' ]; then
    eval "$('/d/anaconda3/Scripts/conda.exe' 'shell.bash' 'hook')"
fi
# <<< conda initialize <<<
export PATH="/d/anaconda3/Scripts:/d/anaconda3:/d/anaconda3/Library/bin:$PATH"`

I don't know why bash says naconda3 (a is missing)
Second, When I enter conda in upper case letter : CONDA -V
it works...
I don't know why this happens
I edited my bash_profile file both global storage(C drive) and system storage(D drive, I installed git in D drive)
When I enter echo $PATH, results are same as below(original was one-line, I line-breaked the output to see it more clearly)
D:naconda3vs\oss;
D:naconda3vs\oss\Library\mingw-w6in;
D:naconda3vs\oss\Library\usin;
D:naconda3vs\oss\Librarin;
D:naconda3vs\oss\Scripts;
D:naconda3vs\\osin;
D:naconda3/d/anaconda3/Scripts
:/d/anaconda3
:/d/anaconda3/Library/bin
:/c/Users/KYJ/bin:/mingw64/bin
:/usr/local/bin
:/usr/bin
:/bin
:/mingw64/bin
:/usr/bin
:/c/Users/KYJ/bin
:/d/anaconda3/envs/oss
:/d/anaconda3/envs/oss/Library/mingw-w64/bin
:/d/anaconda3/envs/oss/Library/usr/bin
:/d/anaconda3/envs/oss/Library/bin
:/d/anaconda3/envs/oss/Scripts
:/d/anaconda3/envs/oss/bin
:/d/anaconda3/condabin
:/c/Program Files/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath
:/c/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.7/bin
:/c/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.7/libnvvp
:/c/Python311/Scripts:/c/Python311
:/c/Program Files/Microsoft/jdk-11.0.16.101-hotspot/bin
:/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Intel/Shared Libraries/redist/intel64/compiler
:/c/Windows/system32
:/c/Windows
:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem
:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0
:/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH
:/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common
:/c/Program Files/NVIDIA Corporation/NVIDIA NvDLISR
:/c/Program Files/NVIDIA/CUDNN/v8.9/bin
:/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/130/Tools/Binn
:/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin
:/d/Android/SDK/platform-tools
:/c/Program Files/dotnet
:/d/ffmpeg/bin
:/d/anaconda3/envs/spleeterEnv/Scripts
:/d/anaconda3/envs/kyj/Scripts
:/c/Program Files/NVIDIA Corporation/Nsight Compute 2022.2.0
:/c/Users/KYJ/AppData/Roaming/nvm
:/c/Program Files/nodejs
:/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Windows Performance Toolkit
:/cmd
:/d/anaconda3
:/d/anaconda3/Library/mingw-w64/bin
:/d/anaconda3/Library/usr/bin
:/d/anaconda3/Library/bin
:/d/anaconda3/Scripts
:/c/Users/KYJ/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps
:/c/Users/KYJ/AppData/Local/GitHubDesktop/bin
:/d/Microsoft VS Code/bin
:/c/Users/KYJ/AppData/Local/afreeca:/c/Users/KYJ/AppData/Roaming/npm
:/d/flutter/bin
:/c/Users/KYJ/.dotnet/tools
:/c/Program Files/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath
:/c/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.7/bin
:/c/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.7/libnvvp
:/c/Python311/Scripts
:/c/Python311
:/c/Program Files/Microsoft/jdk-11.0.16.101-hotspot/bin
:/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Intel/Shared Libraries/redist/intel64/compiler
:/c/Windows/system32
:/c/Windows
:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem
:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0
:/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH
:/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common
:/c/Program Files/NVIDIA Corporation/NVIDIA NvDLISR
:/c/Program Files/NVIDIA/CUDNN/v8.9/bin
:/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/130/Tools/Binn
:/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin
:/d/Android/SDK/platform-tools
:/c/Program Files/dotnet
:/d/ffmpeg/bin
:/d/anaconda3/envs/spleeterEnv/Scripts
:/d/anaconda3/envs/kyj/Scripts
:/c/Program Files/NVIDIA Corporation/Nsight Compute 2022.2.0
:/c/Users/KYJ/AppData/Roaming/nvm
:/c/Program Files/nodejs
:/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Windows Performance Toolkit
:/cmd
:/d/anaconda3
:/d/anaconda3/Library/mingw-w64/bin
:/d/anaconda3/Library/usr/bin
:/d/anaconda3/Library/bin
:/d/anaconda3/Scripts
:/c/Users/KYJ/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps
:/d/Microsoft VS Code/bin
:/c/Users/KYJ/AppData/Local/afreeca
:/c/Users/KYJ/AppData/Roaming/npm
:/d/flutter/bin
:/c/Users/KYJ/.dotnet/tools
:/usr/bin/vendor_perl
:/usr/bin/core_perl


Git-bash is a Unix-like environment. In Unix-like environments \a is a special charcter. Either you use D:\\anaconda3 in git-bash to quote a backslash with the second backslash or D:/anaconda3. Rewrite your $PATH in ~/.bash_profile

As you can see at the top of my question, there is no single \ at my bash_profiles

They're in $PATH at the end of PATH assignment.

Umm... I didn't modified anything at all since I wrote this question, but today conda command(in lowercase conda) worked...! I guess this is kind of visual studio code bug or something...
